# how to read a line contents and put them in couple of arrays?

Tags: php

I have the following code which reads one line of a file and put that line into $A:

```
$A=fgets($file_Test); // $A = 1 333 5464 5848
```

Now i would like to put these numbers in 4 arrays. What should i do? // $a=[1]  $b=[333]  $c=[5464]   $d=[5848]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to is use PHP's [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. Just specify " " for the delimiter and you'll end up with a array like this:

```
$array = [1, 333, 5464, 5848]
```

After that, it's as easy as setting your next variables based on array indices.

EDIT: sample usage is this `$array = explode(" ", $a);`

Comment: thanks for your help. It seems that $A is not a string since i do  get nothing for echo $arr [0] or echo arr [1].                      $A=fgets($file_Test);
echo $A; // 1 333 5464 5848
$arr=explode(" ", $A);
echo $arr[0]; // got nothing

Comment: Try printing the array with `print_r($array);` and you'll see all elements. Also look into `file_get_contents($array);` to put an entire file into a string.